# How to redirect to another cgi file after executing some code

Tags: python, redirect, cgi

I have cgi script(gallery.cgi) in python which contains html images and a form which contains a button to delete those images This form also has the name of the image file as a hidden field. When a user clicks on the delete button, the form is submitted and the page goes to delete.cgi.
Now, delete.cgi gets the name of the file and deletes it. Now I have to go back to gallery.cgi and I do not know how to do this. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

To go back, you need to add code for 'redirection'. The logic flows in the following manner:

gallery.cgi submits to delete.cgi >> delete.cgi first reads the input >> then do the actual deletion process of that image/images >> and then finally at the end of the script redirects back to gallery.cgi

If you google for how to do 'http redirection in python', you should find ample results regarding the exact code to use.